# Definition of a minimal set of automorphisms generating an orbit?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definition

By definition, the orbit of a vertex v in a graph G is the set of all vertices f(v) such that f is an automorphism of G.

I wonder whether there is a definition for a minimal set S of automorphisms of G which generates the orbit. That is, for a vertex v in the orbit, the set of all vertices h(v) such that h is an automorphism in S.

(The number of all elements of the minimal set is the same as the number of all elements of the orbit.)

If such a definition exists, what is it?